# <lambda>() takes 1 pos

Tags: python, lambda

I am practicing using the functools.reduce() function with a lambda function. The problem I am having is that I keep getting an error. Here is my code:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> import math
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> reduce( (lambda x: math.sqrt(x)), l )
```

And here is the output:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I have moved parentheses around but nothing seems to work. For some reason, this code works just fine:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce( (lambda x, y: x * y), [1, 2, 3, 4] )
24
>>> reduce( (lambda x, y: x / y), [1, 2, 3, 4] )
0.041666666666666664
```

but I can't see any difference other than that the second example has a second parameter y. Can anybody offer any advice on why I am getting this error?

Comment: Both code samples you have shown are doing two completely different things. One is getting the square root of it's input (but incorrectly uses reduce), while the other is squaring it's input (correctly using reduce)

Comment: The reduce built-in function expects, as an argument, another function of two arguments. Your lambda has only one argument. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce

Comment: As @apollo2020 says. In order to **reduce** you need a function that takes **2** arguments and turns them into a **single** value. What exactly do you expect your output to be?

Comment: Note, your `lambda x: math.sqrt(x)` can be replaced by `math.sqrt`

Comment: The reduce function receives a function with two arguments. That's the reason you're getting that error message.

Comment: Don't feel too badly. About 15 years ago, Guido van Rossum (creator of Python) said that he regretted introducing reduce() to the language, expressed that it was generally misunderstood, and suggested that simply using a for loop is clearer and usually faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
reduce(lambda acc, x: math.sqrt(x), l)
```

The `lambda` passed to `reduce` requires two arguments: the accumulated result and the current value.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I read the documentation and now see the issue.